# Wordpress ( Dir , Filesystem directory paths )

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm a bit lost about paths in Wordpress informant

Here is what I mean
I usually request a file in the same directory like:

```
include ('filename/index.php');
```

but most of Wordpress devs includes it like:

```
include . WP_CONTENT_URL . ('filename/index.php');
```

What is `WP_CONTENT_URL` ?
Where can I learn about the path cost that Wordpress uses?

I searched  WordPress path system
and I didn't find what I needed.

In a nutshell, I need to learn about the cost that Wordpress uses it to define path locations - I just wanna know what to search about
what are the keywords that I should search for to learn about it more?

Comment: here's the key words that i was using 

all paths commands in wordpress - nothing useful
wordpress dir cost - not what i needed exactly
WP_CONTENT_URL - it shows a documentation about the command

Comment: i just need the documentation link - i can go from there (:

Comment: The Question / Answer format that Stack Overflow uses doesn't allow for "what to search about what are the keywords that I should search for to learn about it"-type Questions/Answers. Please check out the [Help Center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q66PI.png), [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).